# visual studio keyboard shortcuts as resource designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internationalization, keyboard-shortcuts, preferences

If I wanted to externalize a keyboard gesture like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, is there a standard way to do this in Visual Studio the way you would with strings and other resources? I can't seem to add "Other" resources in the designer...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Accelerator` resource. Here's some [MSDN info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216.aspx) on how to edit Accelerator resources in manged projects.

Comment: Hey, I can't find it, and docs suggest that is a C++ editor. Is there a reason why it shouldn't be useful for a c# project also,or am I just not seeing it?

Comment: @Berryl: I've added a link that should (hopefully...) get you going in the right direction. Unfortunately, the short answer *seems* to be that managed programs are somewhat...challenged in this respect.